# How to access json objects with key/value name like this "ContractName2.sol:ContractName2"

Tags: javascript, json

How to access the `json` object key/values `abi` and/or `bin`?

```
//File: myFile.json
{
    "contracts": {
        "ContractName1.sol:ContractName1": {
            "abi": "......",
            "bin": "......"
        },
        "ContractName2.sol:ContractName2": {
            "abi": "......",
            "bin": "......"
        },
    }
}
```

I can do the following thing:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + '/myFile.json')
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFile)
jsonObj.contracts.  // ??
```

Unfortunately it is not possible `ContractName1.sol:ContractName1` e.g. like this:

```
jsonObj.contracts.ContractName1.sol:ContractName1.abi
```

Comment: `jsonObj.contracts['ContractName1.sol:ContractName1'].abi` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing json you can use the `dot` notation or use the `[]` along with the name of the key inside of a string or a variable.

```js
const json = {
  "contracts": {
    "ContractName1.sol:ContractName1": {
      "abi": "......",
      "bin": "......"
    },
    "ContractName2.sol:ContractName2": {
      "abi": "......",
      "bin": "......"
    },
  }
};

console.log(json.contracts['ContractName2.sol:ContractName2']);
```